# Simply add an integer value to an existing value of an element in an array using PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Simply how do I add an integer value to an existing value of an element in an array using PowerShell. I can't seem to be able to get the addition to add the value instead of appending the value.

eg. I have an array which I split up from a string into an array. So lets say the values are 1's from a split of a string. So $array[0] = 1, $array[1] = 1 and $array[2] = 1. Then I want the value of $array[1] to become 2. If I say $array[1] += 1; It appends 1 to the value and it becomes "11" instead of 2. If I follow it with a statement of $array[1] -= 1; Then $array[1] will equal to 10. So subtraction works but not addition.

I am search the internet for help but to no avail. Everything I have tried just does not seem to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your array is a string you need to convert string to [int]. Then you can simply add.

```
[int]array[1] + 1
```

This will return 2. Powershell is interpreting your array as a system string- at least by default. That's why it is simply appending to the end... :)

Comment: Thank you Charles worked like a charm. When you hover between languages you loose the syntax. :-)